# Update yAxes when changing xAxes min and max for ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am working on some financial charts and we want the ability to limit the domain of the chart using the xAxes min and max property of ChartJs. Changing these values then calling chart.update() shrinks the domain as expected effectively zooming the chart into a subset of data, however it doesn't seem to update the yAxes max value to be more reasonable to the subset of data now displaying. Is there a way to make the yAxes update according to the data actually being shown in the chart? In the example below you will see the yAxes max is 1600 and then if you click the update button it zooms in and the yAxes should probably have a max of 800-1000 but instead it just remains at 1600.

https://jsfiddle.net/wmLnu7ev/

```
window.updateChart = function () {
    chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.min= moment("10/1/2005 12:00:00 AM");
    chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.max= moment("1/1/2006 12:00:00 AM");
    // Some options here to make the yAxes max value update dynamically based on the data being displayed after zooming in?
  chart.update();
}
```